# Scan an eclipse project from an eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin, project

I'd like to write a plugin for eclipse that performs some operations on an eclipse project.

My question is: how can I scan/obtain the project file list from an eclipse plugin???

Is there something like findfirst / findnext?

Any pointer in the right direction will be appreciated.

Ciao and thanks.

Comment: Sugerman, this is not what I'm looking for. RTFM answer are stupid by themselves. RTFM, argument: Plug-in Development Environment Guide for example, are smarter and useful. BTW, I've already done that, and I've also read Eclipse Plug-ins 3rd Edition book.

Comment: If you had read that book you'd be aware of the IProject interface (it is mentioned 16 times in the book, not including the reference in the back).  From the link I posted it was 5 clicks to the IProject API reference page which lists all available methods and properties, one of which (as explained by Kellindil) does what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterating over your workspace's projects can be done through `org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProjects()`

After that, finding the files you want can be done through a number of ways, easiest would be through `IProjet.members(...)`

Comment: Thanks. What I've been looking for

Answer (score 0):

Since the workspace, projects and folders all implement `IResource`, you can use of the `org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource.accept()` methods to iterate over the contents.